# Finite coverings for torus and quotients of $\mathbb Z^2$

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology

My aim is to find all $6$ sheet and $4$ sheet coverings of a Torus.

So since fundamental group of a Torus is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z^2$ then my goal reduces finding subgroups of $\mathbb Z^2$ whose index is 6 and 4.

From here [Find all subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/193863/find-all-subgroups-of-mathbbz-times-mathbbz)  I know the classification of subgroups of $\mathbb Z^2$

But I cannot exactly find these subgroups of index $4$ and $6$.

A bit hint or answer would be appreciated. I am so confused with all these direct sum and external products.

Comment: A geometric suggestion: If a subgroup $G$ in $(\mathbf{Z} \times \mathbf{Z}, +)$ has a fundamental parallelogram of area $d$, the induced covering on the unit-square torus has $d$ sheets by elementary area considerations.

Comment: okay but I cannot clasify with only considering this? How to start to clasify all of them?

Comment: Admittedly I haven't done the enumeration myself, but that "area" picture seems like a reasonable way to keep track of alternatives visually. For example, the group generated by $(2,0)$ and $(0,2)$ generates a $4$-sheeted covering, the group generated by $(4, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$ generates another, the group generated by $(2, 1)$ and $(0, 2)$ yet another, .... On the other hand, the group generated by $(2, 2)$ and $(0, 2)$ is a lattice we've already encountered, and the lattice generated by $(2, 1)$ and $(1, 2)$ has the "wrong" area.

Comment: Can you suggest me some source to understand these ideas, I think they are somewhat related to smith normal forms like here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2799765/correspondance-between-finite-index-subgroups-of-mathbbz2-and-regular-co but I cannot understand :(

Comment: I'm afraid no references come to mind, but in the hope they might for some other passerby, are you unsure about (i) classifying index-$k$ subgroups of $(\mathbf{Z}\times\mathbf{Z},+)$, (ii) seeing why these correspond to $k$-sheeted coverings of the torus, and/or (iii) some other aspect of the question?

Comment: i)classifying index-k subgroups of (Z×Z,+),

Comment: @Jale'dejaled [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3866261/893012) describes the geometric suggestion proposed by Andrew. Maybe it's useful.